# 2 UILabels placed horizontally in a table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uilabel

I am working on a table view and in the cell I need to create 2 labels horizontally. The first label has fixed content "Location Name:". The second label will have dynamic content and it can be multiple lines. When I first get to the screen, my cell looks like this:

[image: first get in screen]

But when I scroll down and scroll back up, it looks fine:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
var locationNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Location Name:"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

var locationNameContent: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .regular)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    return label
}()

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    setupUI()
}

func setupUI() {

    let locationNameView = createLocationNameContainer(label: locationNameLabel, labelContent: locationNameContent)
    contentView.addSubview(locationNameView)
    contentView.addSubview(locationImage)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        locationImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        locationImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        locationImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        locationImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
        locationNameView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: locationImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 15),
        locationNameView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
        locationNameView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentView.frame.width - 50),
        locationNameView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
    ])
}

func createLocationNameContainer(label: UILabel, labelContent: UILabel) -> UIView {

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.backgroundColor = .green
    containerView.addSubview(label)
    containerView.addSubview(labelContent)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
        label.firstBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContent.firstBaselineAnchor),
        labelContent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        labelContent.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
        labelContent.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
        labelContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
    ])
    return containerView
}

func configure(model: LocationAndPhotoModel) {

    // get the first oject of "data" array of PhotoModel
    let imageURL = model.locationPhotoModel.data.first?.images.medium.url ?? ""
    locationImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL))
    
    // get location name
    locationNameContent.text = model.locationDetail.name
    // get location address
    locationAddressContent.text = model.locationDetail.address_obj.address_string
}
```

Here's how I implement my tableView:

```
view.addSubview(tableView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
])

extension SearchResultViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos?.count ?? 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchResultTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SearchResultTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        guard self.arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos != nil else {return UITableViewCell()}
        guard let model = arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos?[indexPath.row] else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.configure(model: model)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that scrolling fixes it suggests that you implemented the table view wrong. Please show how you implemented the table view delegate and data source methods.

Comment: I have updated codes

Comment: Why do you call `setupUI` from `setSelected`? `setSelected` can be called many times for a cell. You end up creating and adding views over and over to the cell.

Comment: @HangarRash, I tried to call it from ViewController but issue still the same.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the labels in a horizontal stackview and put layout priority? It seems like you crop the name but not the title? So that means you can just put higher priority on the title?

Comment: @Alex171 - as HangarRash commented, `setupUI` absolutely should not be called from `setSelected` ... but, we'll get to that. First, the code you posted references `locationNameContent` and `locationAddressContent` labels in your `configure()` func, but you don't define `locationAddressContent` nor do you say anything about it in your description (*"I need to create 2 labels horizontally"*). You need to show us what you **want** it to look like.

Comment: @DonMag this issue should be about ```locationNameContent``` and ```locationNameLabel```. As I mentioned, ```locationNameLabel``` is fixed and ```locationNameContent``` is dynamic. the ```func configure()``` is just to get data from viewModel.

Comment: @Alex171 - OK ... still need to clarify how you **want it to look**. For example, do you want this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ6c4.png ... or this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDXV4.png. (I made the images shorter so we can see more rows)

Comment: I want it to look like the first one '''i.stack.imgur.com/KZ6c4.png'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your cell class, `setSelected(...)` will be called many times. Every time a cell is displayed... every time a cell is selected or deselected... etc. So you do NOT want to be adding subviews there.

Instead, setup the UI elements when the cell is init'd:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupUI()
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupUI()
}
```

Next, you can easily accomplish your "two-label" layout with a horizontal `UIStackView`.

Here is your code - modified... I don't have your data, so I used a simple struct with just the "name" string:

```
struct LocationAndPhotoModel {
    var name: String = ""
}

class SearchResultTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "SearchResultTableViewCell"
    
    var locationNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Location Name:"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
        // we don't want to allow the label to be squeezed or stretched
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        return label
    }()
    
    var locationNameContent: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .regular)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        // we don't want to allow the label to be squeezed or stretched
        //  but this is the multiline label, so we ue required - 1
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required - 1, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required - 1, for: .horizontal)
        return label
    }()
    
    var locationImage: UIImageView = {
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return imgView
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupUI()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    // DO NOT implement setSelected, unless you want to customize the
    //  appearance when a cell is selected
    //override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    //  super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    //
    //  // DEFINITELY do not do this here!!!
    //  //setupUI()
    //}
    
    func setupUI() {
        
        let locationNameView = createLocationNameContainer(label: locationNameLabel, labelContent: locationNameContent)
        contentView.addSubview(locationNameView)
        contentView.addSubview(locationImage)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            locationImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            locationImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            
            // I made the image view shorter so we can see more rows
            //  change back to 200 when ready
            locationImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            
            locationImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),

            locationNameView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: locationImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 15),
            locationNameView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            locationNameView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),

            // keep at least 5-points on each side
            locationNameView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            locationNameView.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            
        ])
    }
    
    func createLocationNameContainer(label: UILabel, labelContent: UILabel) -> UIView {
        
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = .green
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        // alignment top, so the left-side label will stay at the top
        //  when the right-side label has multiple lines
        stackView.alignment = .top
        stackView.spacing = 8
        
        // add the labels to the stack view
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(labelContent)
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
        ])
        
        return containerView
    }
    
    func configure(model: LocationAndPhotoModel) {
        
        // get the first oject of "data" array of PhotoModel
        //let imageURL = model.locationPhotoModel.data.first?.images.medium.url ?? ""
        //locationImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL))
        
        // get location name
        locationNameContent.text = model.name // model.locationDetail.name
        
    }
    
}

class SearchResultViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    var arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos: [LocationAndPhotoModel] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
        
        tableView.register(SearchResultTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SearchResultTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // let's add some sample data
        var m = LocationAndPhotoModel(name: "Short")
        arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos.append(m)

        m = LocationAndPhotoModel(name: "Longer Name Here")
        arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos.append(m)

        m = LocationAndPhotoModel(name: "Long enough name that it will probably need to wrap onto multiple lines.")
        arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos.append(m)

        m = LocationAndPhotoModel(name: "Medium Name")
        arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos.append(m)
        
        // let's repeat those 3 times so we have enough to scroll
        for _ in 1...3 {
            arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos.append(contentsOf: arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos)
        }
    }
}

extension SearchResultViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchResultTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SearchResultTableViewCell
        cell.configure(model: arrayOfLocationsAndPhotos[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

When run, it will look like this:

[image]

I don't have your images, so the image view is blue, and I set its height to 100 so we can see more rows.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works for me, the StackView works better than 2 separate UILabels.